# Specifying User Permissions in VBA for Protected Excel Sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I am working with a spreadsheet that is required to be protected before distribution for the sheer sake of data integrity. I have written a function that auto-populates a column based on a drop down list selection. I do not want the user to edit this column so I have it protected, however in order to auto-populate my process un-protects and re-protects the spreadsheet. This is where the issue lies.

I would like users to have all other permissions (e.g. formatting, row insertion, row deletion, etc). However, when the process re-protects the sheet, all permissions are revoked.

Is there a way I can both lock the sheet AND specify which user permissions I would like to grant in VBA?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Worksheet.Protect method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840611.aspx) allows to specify everything that would be available to you when performing the Review ► Changes ► Protect Worksheet command. The parameters are largely optional so they need to be specified explicitly or blank parameters can be passed in with commas as placeholders.

To protect a worksheet with a password and allow column formatting and row insertion:

```
With Worksheets("Sheet One")
    .Protect Password:="myPassword", Contents:=True, _
             AllowFormattingColumns:=True, AllowInsertingRows:=True
    'insert a row
    .Rows("9:9").EntireRow.Insert CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
End With
```

See the [Worksheet.Protect method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840611.aspx) for a full list of available options.

Another option is the `UserInterfaceOnly`. This stops the user from predetermined actions on the worksheet but allows VBA procedures to perform actions that would otherwise be restricted.

```
With Worksheets("Sheet One")
    .Protect Password:="myPassword", UserInterfaceOnly:=True, Contents:=True, _
                 AllowFormattingColumns:=True, AllowInsertingRows:=True
    'insert a column; the user cannot do this
    .Columns(2).EntireColumn.Insert CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
End With
```

This latter behavior allow you more freedom in your VBA procedures without having to continually unprotect and reprotect the worksheet.